# Finding Maximum value in an Array of Objects where numer is a part of string, most optimal solution and write tests

Tags: javascript

I have this code which finding max value from object array where number is part of string:

```
var stringArray = [
{ name: 'string 1' },
{ name: 'string 2' },
{ name: 'string 11' },
{ name: 'string 3' },
{ name: 'string 10' }
];
var customModuleRe = new RegExp('\\d+');
var getMax = function () {
    let max = 0, current;
    for (let i = 0, count = stringArray.length; i < count; i++) {
        current = customModuleRe.exec(stringArray[i].name);
        if (current) {
            let num = parseInt(current[0]);
            if (!isNaN(num) && num > max) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
};
```

I must change this code to be clean, the most optimal and readable. In my opinion i need to use `map` function but i don't know how i can find max value. I've made this:

```
let max, current;
getMax.map(function(a) {
    current = customModuleRe.exec(a.name);
    if (current) {
            let num = parseInt(current[0]);
            //max
        }
});
```

Can someone help me to find the fatest solution? Maybe i need to use `reduce()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math.max` with spread syntax and `map()` method.

```js
var stringArray = [
{ name: 'string 1' },
{ name: 'string 2' },
{ name: 'string 11' },
{ name: 'string 3' },
{ name: 'string 10' }
];

var max = Math.max(...stringArray.map(e => e.name.match(/\d+$/)))
console.log(max)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Specifically, Math.max can take a [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Parameters) number of arguments, like `Math.max(1,2,3,4)` or `Math.max(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`. The `...` operator 'spreads' an array-like object into those arguments, which is convenient.

Comment: i was testing this both codes and you can see result on: [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-and-for) and my question is - is it posible to make this code working faster?

Comment: If you are looking for speed i think `for` loop is better option. Here is my version https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2379/