# object array, what are the best practices to make my code readable when I'm looking for a maximum value

Tags: javascript, code-cleanup

I have this code which finding max value from object array where number is part of string:

```
var stringArray = [
{ name: 'string 1' },
{ name: 'string 2' },
{ name: 'string 11' },
{ name: 'string 3' },
{ name: 'string 10' }
];
var customModuleRe = new RegExp('\\d+');
var getCustomModuleNumber = function () {
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray .length; i++) {
        var current = customModuleRe.exec(stringArray [i].name);
        if (current) {
            var num = parseInt(current[0]);
            if (!isNaN(num) && num > max) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
};
```

I must change this code to be clean, the most optimal, readable, compatible with `ES6`, cleanliness and code quality. For example i need to use:

`for (let i = 0, j = stringArray.length; i < j; i++)`

instead of:

`for (var i = 0; i < stringArray .length; i++)`

Can you find more and explain me why i need to do it? This code should be the fastest and contaible with good code rules.

Comment: what does not work with the answer of your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866104/finding-maximum-value-in-an-array-of-objects-where-numer-is-a-part-of-string-mo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some high level suggestions:

- dont use for loops if there exist Array prototypes that do the job: e.g. `Array.map` and `Math.reduce`. The idea is eliminate the loop iterator temp variable. Sometimes, when u find the most appropriate Array prototype method you find loop iterators like `i` become unneccessary. Finding the right iterator method can be a real gem and save a lot of code.
- use `Math.max` instead of `if` statement. The thinking here is most of the time we start with `if` statements throughout our code. Eventually we find we dont need it when we learn to leverage javascript better.
- use `apply` to make `Math.max` work on lists. Most javascript functions works on both arguments and arrays. The array form is generally harder to read and is overlooked but can save you a lot of time. `Math.max.apply`.
- use regex capture groups, e.g. `/(\\d+)/`, this will parse the string for you and pluck out the number portions. This is done in the v8 engine without you doing heavy lifting in javascript
- no need for Regexp object, you can use regexp direct in your code, unquote your string and use slashes.

The above ate general rules. I can think of multiple solutions to your problem:

1. Array.map, regex, parseInt, Math.max.apply
2. Array.reduce, regex, parseInt, Math.max

You can swap out regex with split as another OP has posted.

There are many solutions.

My favourite is Math.reduce since it crunches arrays into a single result. But the challenge for you is to figure it out since the syntax is not welcoming for newcomers.

Comment: a `for` loop is still faster than every array iterator method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const getMax = _ =>
  Math.max(...stringArray.map( n =>
      n.name.split(" ")[1]
  ));
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/dofacubiza/1/edit?console)

Comment: what means "_" before Math.max? Is it same as "()"?

Comment: @harry yes, kind of

Answer (score 0):

Other solution reducing the array:

```
'use strict';

const stringArray = [
  { name: 'string 1' },
  { name: 'string 2' },
  { name: 'string 11' },
  { name: 'string 3' },
  { name: 'string 10' },
];

const max = stringArray.reduce((previousValue, currentElement) => {
  const currentValue = parseInt(currentElement.name.split(' ', 2)[1], 10) || -Infinity;
  return (currentValue > previousValue ? currentValue : previousValue);
}, -Infinity);

console.log('max value', max);
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the easiest way to do it, but it's another way to do it using functional js principals which once you have the utilities you can put the functionality together like lego blocks, with every part of the code being testable as all the utilities have only a single responsibility.

```js
// import utilities from a library like Ramda.js
const {
  compose, curry, map, reduce,
  prop, max, split, last, match
} = R

const stringArray = [
  { name: 'string 1' },
  { name: 'string 2' },
  { name: 'string 11' },
  { name: 'string 3' },
  { name: 'string 10' },
]

// read the name property of an object and find the number
const extractNumber = compose(Number, match(/\d+$/), prop('name'))

// map over the objects and find the number, then reduce the array of
// numbers to find the highest value
const getMaximumValue = compose(
  reduce(max, 0),
  map(extractNumber)
)

console.log(
  getMaximumValue(stringArray)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@latest/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```